Angular version 18 - Alternate of SpyNgModuleFactoryLoader for unit testing of lazy loading Module
I am trying to write a unit test case for a lazy-loaded module with a canMatch guard. I have reviewed multiple threads on Stack Overflow, but the solutions provided are either outdated or not workable. The SpyNgModuleFactoryLoader option was deprecated in Angular version 13 and is no longer available in the latest version 18. Are there any alternative solutions for testing a lazy-loaded module with loadChildren?


it('should navigate to "auth" redirects you to /auth', async () => {
    store.dispatch(UserActions.loginSuccess({ data: MockData.UserLoggedIn }));
    router.navigate(['auth']).then(() => {
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/auth/dashboard');
    })
});


Why do you need to load lazy loaded module to unit test guard? Can't you just test the return value of guard (true/false/urltree)? If canMatch guard returns true, then the module will be loaded, I don't see a point in testing angular internals (i.e. whether lazy loaded module will be loaded when guard allows that).

Thanks @Adrial for your reply. I just want to test loadChildren but not the canMatch part. In SonarQube, I am getting this as uncovered code. For this reason, I am writing this unit testing. Any help?

Added screen shot of SonarQube

Is this just writing unit tests for the sake of 100% code coverage even though you would cover angular internals? Somehow you got the previous path marked as anonymous covered, and I guess without testing loadChildren. I think there are many other ways you can get code coverage on this line, perhaps E2E tests. IF you really need just to get this line covered, create a routing testing module in the test that imports the same routes as are provided in the screenshot and perform router navigation to this route. But as I stated, this test is useless.

See comments in question testing angular lazy loaded

Thanks @Adrian. I have tried that example before posting this question but the packages which are used in this example are no longer available in the Angular Version 18. ng test --code-coverage does not consider any module files in coverage but in case of SonarQube it is. As of now I have excluded module files from the coverage (added in the screen shot).

I meant the example provided in the comments, i.e this, routingtestingmodule is still available in angular, so I don't know which package you mean

Here's how I do it in Angular 14, FWIW.
In module:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
   ...
      { path: 'myModule', loadChildren: () => 
          import('./myModule/myModule.module').then(m => m.MyModule) },
...
    ]
  }];

and then in the UT:
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        LoggerTestingModule, 
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
    });
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });

  it('should load MyModule when path is myModule', async () => {
    const { MyModule } = await import('./myModule/myModule.module');
    const config = router.config[0];

    if (config.children) {
      const x: (Route | undefined) = config.children.find(rc => rc.path === 'myModule');
      expect(await (x?.loadChildren?.())).toEqual(MyModule)
    }
  });


Hi @500,
I have tried this and this is working. Do you have any idea, how we can write test for to navigate with canMatch guard. I have added code in the question (in the bottom)

@chetan: I don't have experience with that, I'm afraid.
